# Enable autocomplete user dictionary for all files in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have a dictionary file (`"english.txt"`, from unix `/usr/share/dict/words`), and I would like this to be loaded for any buffer (or would this make it too slow?)

The documentation for autocomplete only talks about mode specific and user specific (but still in the mode sense!), and also loading dictionaries based on extension.

How to go about making Emacs Speak English?

Comment: I'm afraid that even if Emacs will be able to cope with the size of the dictionary, there will be too many false positives to make it useful. Or you would have to start completing too late (after typing 4-5 characters), which will make it not really useful. Perhaps... if you only selected the long words, but even then there would be collisions between the possible non-words used in the program and the words from the dictionary etc...

Comment: @wvxw I agree, though once it is possible maybe we are able to find a way to make it work...

Answer (score 1):

You may look at this [1](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode). As I read the description I thought that is what you need just look at the example:

I cant post so here the link: 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode#toc5